# how to prevent external url append to localhost url when using react link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my localhost my append to the external URL I m going to. how to prevent this?

```
<Link to={article.url}>
     <img src={article.urlToImage} alt="thumb"/>
</Link>
```

http://localhost:3000/https://bleacherreport.com/articles/2910730-fifa-21-breaking-down-standard-ultimate-covers-and-newest-features

Comment: this depends on the article.url value. it should have "/". For ex.  article.url = "/storage/images"

Comment: my url start with this: "https:// bleacherreport.com/articles/2910730-fifa-21-breaking-down-standard-ultimate-covers-and-newest-features"

Comment: try adding "http://" or "https://"

Comment: i have https://

Comment: change image url?

Comment: my bad. i'll just try to reproduce this

Comment: Hello, I saw this [discussion](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1147), if you want external url just use <a href="" />

Answer (score 2):

Go for simple anchor tags.

React-router's Link tags are good if that page lies on one of your routes. Otherwise, just use good-old `anchor tags`

```
const url = 'https://bleacherreport.com/articles/2910730-fifa-21-breaking-down-standard-ultimate-covers-and-newest-features'

<a href={url} />
```

Comment: thanks i thought link can be use in this case as well.

Comment: Nope. I don't think so. Link doesn't allow the page to reload. So, the react-router basically searches the route in your component. It won't find it and thus an error.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using redirection to another url which is a part of your project , then use

`<Link to=""> ....<Link>`

example :

```
const my_url = '/contact-us'

<Link to={my_url}>Click here </Link>
```

---

But if you are redirection to external link , like : google.com , amazon.com , etc use old `<a href="link">....</a>`

example : `<a href="https://www.google.com/"> click here</a>`

In your case the soliution is :

```
const article = {
  url : "https://www.google.com/"
}

<a href={article.url}>
     <img src={article.urlToImage} alt="thumb"/>
</a>
```